# How to chain an anonymous function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to chain an anonymous function in jQuery but it's not working. I get an error "Error: XML filter is applied to non-XML value ...". What's the proper syntax or is there an effect function I can use which doesn't do anything visually and which wraps my function?

My example:  `$item.appendTo($list).(function() {.....}());`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? This makes no sense to me at all. Are you trying to invoke a function such that `this` is set to `$item`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chaining works by returning the original jQuery object as a result of invocation of the given chainable function.  Hypothetically, to chain your anonymous functions, you must 'return' the original jQuery object.

However, your function has to be callable from the context of the jQuery object.  For example, there exists the function

```
$item.appendTo
```

However, there is no function on the jQuery object that is reachable by:

```
$item.(function(){ })
```

Think of it like this.  Let us say you have the following object:

```
var obj = { foo: function(){ console.log(1); } };
```

The 'foo' declaration is accessible as a property/declaration on obj.  But what, exactly, is the declaration you are referencing with an anonymous function?

```
obj.(function(){ })
```

The only way you could give your anonymous function an execution context of the jQuery object, would be to do a 'call' on it

```
(function(){ }).call($item, args);
```

If you were wanting to chain this, you could theoretically do so by:

```
(function(){ return this; }).call($item, args).appendTo($other);
```

But I'm not sure what you'd gain.  Your best bet is to simply do:

```
$item.appendTo($list);
(function($obj){ })($item);
```

Or, if you are starting off with a selector:

```
var $item = $('#someID').appendTo($list);
(function($obj){ })($item);
```

Though, at this point anonymous functions aren't as useful, so I would simply:

```
var someFunc = function($obj){ };
$item.appendTo($list);
someFunc($item);
```

Comment: Something like: $item.appendTo($list).(function($){/*do your stuff*/ return $;})(jQuery);

Comment: returning of the jQuery object is need if you want to continue the chaining after the anonymous function. If it is the last one (*and do not want anything returned for further use*) you do not need it.

Comment: @rcravens that is what I thought at first as well, but you can't call anything on $item that doesn't already exist as a function. See update above.

Comment: That is why there is the `.each` method. It allowes you to run custom functions on elements of current jquery object.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method

```
$item.appendTo($list).each( function() {.....} );
```

Alternatively you can extend the jquery object with your own functions ([`jQuery.fn.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/)).

```
$.fn.extend({
    myOwnFunc: function(){
         /*do whatever*/
         return this; // to allow for further chaining.
    }
});
```

and now you can call `$item.appendTo($list).myOwnFunc()`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$item.appendTo($list).(function() {.....})();
```

Totally forgot to mention returning $;